# How to increase applicationDidEnterBackground in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate, appdelegate

I call one api in `applicationDidEnterBackground`, but `applicationDidEnterBackground` method returns after 5 seconds so how could I increase timer or after api finish then only `applicationDidEnterBackground` will return all of us suggest use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`

But I don't know how to use it can anyone guide me?

Here is my code

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    NSString *link=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.askpundit.com/dev/js_chat/getNewRequest.php?updateStatus=%@&clientid=%@",UpdateStatus,[self getSetting:@"Clientid"]]; 
    NSURLRequest *request=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];  

    NSURLConnection *connaction=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (connaction)
    {
        responsedata=[NSMutableData data];

        NSLog( @"Data Saved");

    }
}
```

Can any one guide me how return `applicationDidEnterBackground` after my call finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you surmise, `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` is what you should use.  It's very straightforward.  This snippet is minimally proofread, and incomplete - but demonstrates the approach.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    _completionTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:_completionTask];
        _completionTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
    // begin your NSURLConnection, etc.
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    if( _completionTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid ) {
         [application endBackgroundTask:_completionTask];
         _completionTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

Comment: Hey @NSBum thanks for response yea i got solution any way thanks for responding me